# Fails to apply condition through jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I just want to show **Customer Name Row** only when **Balnce Row** have **Negative Integer Value** through jQuery if the **Balnce Row** have **Positive Integer Value** than it will show **Customer Name Row** .

After multiple times  I'll try to do this while using if/else condition but can't got my required result. Kindly , help me out, to sort my problem. My **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/innoo_devil/ctq13qsy/)** is this. And Code is Give Below.
 I'm very thankful to you. :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.pay').change(function(){
      var pay = $(this).val()-0;
      var subtoal = $('.subtotal').val() - 0;
      $('.payback').val(pay-subtoal);
    }); 
    $('.custname').change(function(){
      var n=  $('.payback').val()-0;
      if(n>=0) {
        $('.custname').hide();  //...Do stuff for +ve num
      } else {
        $('.custname').show();  //...Do stuff for -ve num
      }         
    });
  });       
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="" method="post" > 
  <table class="table table-bordered ">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="0"><b>SubTotal :</b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="subtotal" class="form-control subtotal"></td>
      </tr>

      <tr class="pnotes">
        <td colspan="0"><b>Cash Receive:</b></td>   
        <td colspan="0"><input type="text" name="pay" class="form-control pay">
      </tr>
      <tr class="pnotes">
        <td colspan="0"><b>Balnce : </b></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="payback"  class="form-control payback"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="custname">
        <td colspan="0"><b>Customer Name</b></td>
        <td colspan="0"><input type="text" name="custname" class="form-control"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>    
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this helps. You can hide customer name field on page load and then display it based on the value present in Balance field. Code comments below.

```js
$('.pay').change(function () {
 var pay = $(this).val() - 0;
 var subtoal = $('.subtotal').val() - 0;
 $('.payback').val(pay - subtoal).trigger("blur"); //Added .trigger("blur")
});

//Modified code below
$('.payback').on("blur", function () {
 var n = $.isNumeric($(this).val()) ? $(this).val() - 0 : 0;
 if (n >= 0)
  $('.custname').hide();//...Do stuff for +ve num
 else
  $('.custname').show();//...Do stuff for -ve num
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
 <table class="table table-bordered ">
  <tbody>

   <tr>
    <td colspan="0">
     <b>SubTotal :</b>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" name="subtotal" class="form-control subtotal">
    </td>
   </tr>

   <tr class="pnotes">
    <td colspan="0">
     <b>Cash Receive:</b>
    </td>
    <td colspan="0">
     <input type="text" name="pay" class="form-control pay">
   </tr>
   <tr class="pnotes">
    <td colspan="0">
     <b>Balnce : </b>
    </td>
    <td>
     <input type="text" name="payback" class="form-control payback">
    </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="custname" style="display:none;">
    <td colspan="0">
     <b>Customer Name</b>
    </td>
    <td colspan="0">
     <input type="text" name="custname" class="form-control">
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot sir, will you give me one more favour ? if you tell me why my code is not working I'm very thankfull to you !

Comment: @Newbiee You are binding the event to customer name field instead of balance field ` $('.custname').change(function(){`. If you see my code above, I only changed the event to balance field and then calling `.trigger("blur")` on cash receive feild.

Comment: Thanks a Lot sir :)